# Invalid array length using a variable from the component and Math.floor

Tags: reactjs

I’m trying to display some icon stars depending on the rate number given. So this numbers may have decimals. For this problem, I’ve tried including a Math.floor to display the first star icons and it worked on the code sandbox that I've created to test this ([check it out](https://codesandbox.io/s/books-rating-0j8ke?file=/src/App.js)), but once I’ve implemented on my project it gives me this error:

[image]

What could possibly make this error happen? It’s basically the same code that I’m using.

I’ve already tested what type of value it’s given me, and it’s a number. Even because I changed the number to a non-decimal and the code worked, with the code like this:

```
{[...Array(rate_number)].map(() => (
    <i className="icon icon-arrow mr-2 text-yellow font-weight-bold h-100" />
))}
```

The numbers that it will receive will be under the number 5, fyi.

My project has Next.JS and TypeScript, but I don’t think this is the problem.

**Edit**: As requested bellow, here is the result of the console.log for the Math.floor and the variable itself:

[image]

And the result:

[image]

Comment: I've edited my question with the results. It gives me numbers. But it also runs the code again and give my other values. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Yes. RangeError is thrown when the length property of an Array is negative, a number higher than 2**32 or not a number. While you can do Array(undefined), you can't do Array(Math.floor(undefined)). Math.floor(undefined) returns NaN, and Array(NaN) produces this RangeError.

Regardless of that, check that rate_number is a positive number before running the chunk of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mentioned it in the comment, but I leave it as an answer as well.

It happens that **rate_number** is undefined.

You can do `Array(undefined)`, which creates an Array of length 1 ([ undefined ]). You can also do `Array(0)`, which creates an empty array([]).

But doing `Math.floor(undefined)` returns `NaN`. And doing `Array(NaN)` produces a `RangeError`.

Check the **rate_number** is always 0 or more before running the code, or set it to 0 if its undefined.